# Aptana complaining about empty script

Tags: html, xhtml, aptana, aptana3

I have the following line of code in **Aptana**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

or else the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js" />
```

which is the same thing.
However Aptana complains with the following warning:

`should trim empty <script>`

which doesn't make sense since the script is provided in an external file, not inline.
The following is accepted without warning errors, though wastes one line of space:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js">
</script>
```

Anyone have any idea of why Aptana is wrongly reporting a warning and whether
there is a way to ensure Aptana only displays *sensible* error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in the head section of your html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.7.2.min.js" %>
```

Hope this helps.

- Corix

Comment: I tried your code as follows in my rails app using Aptana Studio 3 and it works for me:

    `<script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>`

However, the self closing tag doesn't:

    `<script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" />`

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4724) on the issue, and it will be fixed in the next (3.2.0) release.

Answer (score 0):

For Aptana Studio users:

Windows: go to Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation

(Mac: go to Aptana Studio > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation)

Select HTML Tidy Validator then some collapse-able options will appear. Select Elements, it will show a list of options.

Now go to the bottom of the list and you'll see "Trim Empty Elements": change it from `warning` to `ignore`.